# JavaFx TableView UI not loaded completely

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a problem with my tableView created from a fxml.

So basically it works fine, but within the 1 call of the tableview not every cell is "created(?)". I mean I have 10 rows and only the first one is fully created and the other ones are created partially. Like on the screenshot:
[image]

As you can see only the first row is complete (is also preselected).

I have also a button "clear table" which removes the entered criteria and after clicking it the table updates and is shown complete:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you change the size of the table's container programatically? Can you post a minimal example exhibiting this problem? As a workaround `table.layout()` may help...

Comment: well, I found the solution one minute ago: It was the way I created my Scene

Answer (score 0):

well, I found the solution one minute ago: It was the way I created my Scene

```
Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 640, 480. Color.ALICEBLUE);
```

Changing it to

```
Scene scene = new Scene(pane, Color.ALICEBLUE);
```

solved the problem